# Django TypeError: force_authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, tdd

Test case **setUp()** that first creates a user and the try's to force authenticate the user but a wired error occurs...

> **TypeError: force_authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

```
class PrivateUserApiTest(TestCase):
    """ Test API that require authentication """

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = create_user(
            email="test@test.com",
            password="testpass",
            name="testName"
        )
        print(self.user)
        self.client = APIClient
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user) # <--
```

Comment: there should be self.client=APIClient()

Comment: First check if your force_authenticate method has first argument self, such as: 
`def force_authenticate(self, user, other, arguments):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `@BhavyaParikh` said, instead of this:

```
self.client = APIClient
```

do this:

```
self.client = APIClient()
```